# Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dependency-injection, inject

I created a project and added **https://github.com/google/inject.dart** to my project but when i want to generate dependency injection
I got below Error when i want to build **DI** with `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 489ms

[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 9.2s

[SEVERE] Failed to snapshot build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
[SEVERE] lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/graph.dart:20:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'graph/injector_graph.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/graph.dart:21:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'graph/injector_graph_resolver.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/graph.dart:22:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'graph/summary_reader.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/summary.dart:14:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'summary/injectable_summary.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/summary.dart:15:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'summary/injector_summary.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/summary.dart:16:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'summary/library_summary.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/summary.dart:17:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'summary/module_summary.dart';
     ^
lib/q35/injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator/lib/src/summary.dart:18:6: Error: The language version override has to be the same in the library and its part(s).
part 'summary/provider_summary.dart';
     ^

pub finished with exit code 78
```

and here is my **inject_generator_build.yaml**:

```
# Read about `build.yaml` at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_config
builders:
  inject_generator:
    target: ":inject_generator"
    import: "package:inject_generator/inject_generator.dart"
    builder_factories:
      - "summarizeBuilder"
      - "generateBuilder"
    build_extensions:
      ".dart":
        - ".inject.summary"
        - ".inject.dart"
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source
```

Comment: I finally solved this issue when i update inject.dart library to dart version 2

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error when part of my flutter install was corrupted. I solved it by running reloading my flutter using `flutter channel beta` `flutter upgrade` `flutter channel stable` `flutter upgrade`